# How to call web Api returning List of Objects

Tags: asp.net-web-api

i am trying to call web Api that returns a list of object but it always throws an error : Internal Server Error

my code as below:
Web API

```
// GET: api/UploadFileStructures
        [ResponseType(typeof( IEnumerable<UploadFileStructure>))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetUploadFileStructuresByMovieId(int MovieDetailId)
        {
            IEnumerable<UploadFileStructure> uploaFileStructures= db.UploadFileStructures.Where(u=>u.MovieDetailId== MovieDetailId).AsEnumerable();
            return Ok(uploaFileStructures);
        }
```

Http Request:

```
  using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                //client.BaseAddress = UsersLogin;
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));            

     var response = client.GetAsync(String.Format(GetUploadFileStructuresByMovieIdUrl, MovieDetailId)).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                UploadFileStructureDtls= response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IQueryable<UploadFileStructure>>().Result;

            }
        }
```

response.IsSuccessStatusCode is returing false and response  returning " Internal Server Error"

Comment: Dig into the details of the internal server error as this is too generic to tell you what the actual problem is

Comment: Access the webapi in the server to view the error message!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on this line of your server code:

```
IEnumerable<UploadFileStructure> uploaFileStructures= db.UploadFileStructures.Where(u=>u.MovieDetailId== MovieDetailId).AsEnumerable();
```

If you set a breakpoint there, you should be able to see the actual error message that is generated.

Comment: i found that issue db.UploadFileStructures.Where returning relative objects the it is throwing error .

Do i need to return only single class object if that class object contanis any other relative class objects throwing error.

In the above case UploadFIleStructure return 3 records and each records again mapped with FIleStructure class objects.